# Amazon Route53 redirection

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a domain example.com in AWS and have got one load balancer and one ec2 instance. Trying to setup https with certificate from AWS.

Route53 setup and A record setup is done as follows for domain to load balancer.

domain name - *.example.com

Name:-
example.com.

Type:-
- Ip4

Alias Target :- dns name of load balancer.

My web is a spring based web and it redirect user to landing page if user access www.example.com  --->>> www.example.com/landing.

After all the setup, if i access like the below url, it is working fine.

https://www.example.com/landing

But if i access without www,

https://example.com/landing --> It leads to browser security page.(Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ...)

Our certificate is based on the domain name *.example.com.

If I simply access, https://example.com/ ---> It gets redirected to http://example.com/landing -- > Spring app redirects like this with http.

http://www.test.com/landing leads to certificate trust error. (https://example.com/landing).

Getting site can not be reached error if i simply access, http://www.example.com/

I am looking for URL redirection to https if user access using http or without www or without any scheme.  Not sure if i have to configure anything in Route53.

Also, Do i need to configure in my app to redirect to https?

Comment: Did you install the certificate on your EC2 instance, or is it on the load balancer? Is it an ELB?

Comment: The site you have mentioned in this question seems to be working fine... which suggests you have chosen it as an arbitrary example, but the people who own the domain might not endorse your use of their name for this purpose.  There are formally established practices of using http://example.com and http://example.org for this purpose.  Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Certificate was installed on Load Balancer. My site is still http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current certificate [should not work for the root](https://serverfault.com/questions/310530/should-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-secure-both-the-root-domain-as-well-as-the-sub), i.e. https://test.com

Either purchase an alternate name for https://test.com or use only www.test.com as your website. You do not need to change anything in Route53 for now. You probably do need to add redirection in your webserver/app to use HTTPS-only, unless you want to leave it to the users.

Comment: I have the certificate setup in Load Balancer and not in my website. My website is still http and load balancer is being exposed as https. Do I need to still redirect to https in my website? If so, Do i need to setup https stuff in my website also.

Comment: If your load balancer forwards from port 443 to port 80, then you don't need to handle HTTPS on the EC2 instance. This looks like your setup.

Comment: Yes, this is how it is been setup in Load balancer. However, if i access https://example.com/, i am redirecting user to landing page like, example.com/landing. In this case, it is redirecting back to http as http://example.com/landing

Comment: Use your web server's in-built rewrite functions to rewrite all HTTP requests to HTTPS. You don't however need to install a certificate on the instance if your are offloading SSL to the load balancer.

Comment: The problem is, even i access using https like https://example.com/ it redirects back to http like http://example.com/landing.  Not sure about servers rewrite in Spring boot tomcat. Will have to explore this.